# Laptop being assigned IPv4 address out of router's DHCP range

Tags: router, dhcp, linksys, ipv4

I have a laptop connecting wirelessly to an E4200 Linksys router. The router is configured to use DHCP with a range from #.#.#.100 to #.#.#.254. However, the laptop is being assigned an IP address of #.#.#.80 which is below the specified DHCP range. I'm not sure how this is even possible. Also, the laptop has Internet connectivity.

Out of curiosity I performed a `ping -a` on my laptop's assigned IP address from another client and it's showing a completely different host name.

Any ideas on why the laptop is being assigned an IP address out of the DHCP range specified in the router?

Comment: could you have another dhcp server running in your subnet?

Comment: Make sure you are not using a static address as well..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the `ipconfig /all` output.  What is it showing as the DHCP server.  Is it coming from the router/device you expect?  Perhaps you have a rogue DHCP server somewhere.

Comment: Precise answer. And correct IMO.

Comment: The DHCP server is different from the other clients. I wonder how I can change the DHCP server to point to the correct one?

Comment: The problem isn't the laptop, it's the rogue DHCP server.

Comment: You need to turn off the other DHCP server.  You generally should never have two running on the same network unless you have performed special steps to setup clustering.  Multiple DHCP servers on the same network causes badness.

Comment: @Zoredache The DHCP server that the laptop shows is actually pointing to one of the two DNS servers we have in the network. The other clients are pointing to the router as the DHCP server.

Comment: @BryanRoth you can't choose which DHCP server your clients 'point to'. DHCP is a broadcast protocol - the clients shout out asking for an IP address and if a server responds, great. As others have pointed out, you need to turn off the unwanted DHCP service.

Comment: @BryanRoth If it's pointing to your DNS server then you know where your rogue DHCP server is :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your laptop probably had previously the #.#.#.80 address from a previous connection (it was connected elsewhere, or you just reconfigured your current router). After reboot, it asked to renew the ip address to the Linksys, which have the same ip address than the previous router. The answer was lost or something gone wrong, so your laptop kept its previous address.

You have internet connectivity because both LAN have same settings (same gateway, and same DNS which is usualy the gateway).